# Browserify require('restangular') returns empty object

Tags: angularjs, browserify, commonjs

Im facing a problem when I try to use browserify, angularjs and restangular.

When I try to require the npm or bower module, for example require('restangular), browserify returns empty object. This happens when i require any bower or npm modules. When I try to require any local file, everything is working fine.

file structure:

```
bower_components/
src/
  -client
      -app
          app.js
          backend
                backend.module.js
                -test
                    test.module.ls
                    test.js
node_modules/
```

app.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    require('angular');

    var rest = require('restangular');
    console.log(rest);

    module.exports = angular
        .module('app', [
            require('restangular').name,
            require('./test/test.module').name,
        ]);
})();
```

package.json

```
"browserify": {
    "transform": [
        "browserify-shim"
    ]
},
"browser": {
    "restangular": "./bower_components/restangular/dist/restangular.js"
},
"browserify-shim": {
    "restangular": "restangular"
}
```

gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    gulp.src(['./src/client/app/app.js'])
    .pipe(plugins.browserify({
        insertGlobals: true,
        debug: true
    }))
    .pipe(plugins.concat('bundled.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/client/js'))
});
```

Can you help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just modify your "browser" part in package.json:

```
"browserify-shim": {
    "angular": {
      "exports": "angular"
    },
 "restangular": {
      "depends": [
        "angular"
      ],
      "exports": "restangular"
    }
}
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your package.json file with this snippet.

```
"browser": {
    "restangular": "./bower_components/restangular/dist/restangular.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "restangular": {
      "depends": [
        "angular",
        "lodash:_"
      ],
      "exports": "null"
    }
  }
```

Solution courtesy of @newtricks from this [discussion](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/749#issuecomment-47983835)